# arabic text shows up as question marks

Tags: php, html, mysqli

i want my php code and database to support arabic language but instead it would show me ???? , here is my code below, i made sure the database and the table is of utf8_general_ci collation. I tried everything, nothing works. my php.ini file already has uft8 as default. Im really starting to think this will never work.

```
<html>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html;charset=UTF-8">
<?php
$mysqli = new Mysqli("localhost","","", "") or mysqli_error($mysqli);
mysqli_query("SET NAMES 'utf8'");
mysqli_query('SET CHARACTER SET utf8');
mysqli_set_charset('utf8', $mysqli); 
$sql = "SELECT Name FROM Mothakirat"; // This SQL statement selects ALL from the table 'Locations'

if ($result = mysqli_query($mysqli, $sql)) // Check if there are results
{
    $resultArray = array();     // If so, then create a results array and a temporary one
    $tempArray = array();           // to hold the data

    while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) // Loop through each row in the result set    
    { 
        $tempArray = $row;    // Add each row into our results array
        array_push($resultArray, $tempArray);
    }
    echo json_encode($resultArray);     // Finally, encode the array to JSON and output the results
}

mysqli_close($con); // Close connections
?>
</html>
```

Comment: I don't know much about arabic but isn't is a 16 bit character set?  Use utf-16?

Comment: ive searched and found out its utf8 for arabic.

Comment: Do you need case insensitive?  If not try utf8_bin.

Comment: @Misunderstood nothing :(

Comment: Try to add a doctype and make it valid html first - maybe that'll help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your calls to `mysql_query()` are probably no doing anything. See http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-query.php You are not passing the second argument. I'd probably go about this using PDO:

```
<html>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html;charset=UTF-8">
<?php
/* Connect to an ODBC database using driver invocation */
$dsn = 'mysql:dbname=testdb;host=127.0.0.1;charset=UTF8;' 
$user = 'dbuser'; // don't hardcode this...store it elsewhere
$password = 'dbpass'; // this too...

try {
  $dbh = new PDO($dsn, $user, $password);
} catch (PDOException $e) {
  echo 'Connection failed: ' . $e->getMessage();
}

$sql = "SELECT :column FROM :table";
$opts = array(
  ':column' => 'Name',
  ':table' => 'Mothakirat'
);
$dbh->beginTransaction();
$statement = $dbh->prepare($sql);
if ($statement->execute($opts)) {
  $resultArray = array();     // If so, then create a results array and a temporary one
  $tempArray = array();           // to hold the data

  while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) // Loop through each row in the result set    
  {
    $tempArray = $row;    // Add each row into our results array
    array_push($resultArray, $tempArray);
  }
  echo json_encode($resultArray);     // Finally, encode the array to JSON and output the results
}
$dbh->commit();
</html>
```

Comment: Did you replace the placeholders with real values (check `$dsn`, $user, and $pass)? you could try removing `beginTransaction()` and `commit()`. They are just good practices but perhaps they are causing issues in this context. What version of PHP are you running?

Comment: @sam I see this is accepted, glad it helped! Did the suggestions above solve the issue? I'm just curious if the transaction caused issues or if the placeholders were to blame, do tell!

Answer (score 0):

Try to convert your file in UTF-8 !

[image]

For me it worked when it wouldn't show the spécial french caracters even if i had "utf 8" in my head.

Comment: OP doesn't seem to have any utf8 characters in their .php file so i doubt this will do anything.